# How to use latest electron-builder with bigint-buffer package?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows, electron, web3js

I'am use package bigint-buffer "^1.1.5" in electron application. After update package electron-builder, project don't builded. There is a error

```
Error: spawn C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Msbuild\Current\Bin ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:285:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:485:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:485:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\Msbuild\\Current\\Bin',
  path: 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\Msbuild\\Current\\Bin',
  spawnargs: [
    'build/binding.sln',
    '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
    '/nologo',
    '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
  ]
}

  ⨯ node-gyp failed to rebuild 'C:\Users\admin\wd\node_modules\bigint-buffer'  failedTask=build stackTrace=Error: node-gyp
failed to rebuild 'C:\Users\admin\wd\node_modules\bigint-buffer'
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\wd\node_modules\@electron\rebuild\src\module-type\node-gyp\node-gyp.ts:131:
16)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Package bigint-buffer uses in package @solana/web3.js

Comment: Hey , Wondering if you was able to fix this issue ! 
thanks.

Comment: @TahaDaboussi I don't think this question is answerable given the little details OPs provided. But usually problem with `node-gyp` come from incompatible versions. Try to check your Python and NodeJS versions.

Comment: Hey @Arkellys Thanks for answering. 
Actually yes I read that a lot , Tried using different versions of NodeJS using NVM down to 14 , 16 , 18 and 21 .
None seems to work , even have python 2.7 , python 3.8 , 3.12 also none seems to fix the problem .

Comment: @TahaDaboussi And you always get the same error as OP's? No more info? The question mention the error happened after updating `electron-builder`, have you tried to see if downgrading this library fix the issue? This could be a starting point.

Comment: Is there a difference in your `node-gyp` versions before and after upgrading `electron-builder`? You can try `npm why node-gyp` or `yarn why node-gyp` to see what version is specified in each case.

Comment: @TahaDaboussi I added an answer which may help you.

Answer (score 0):

`node-gyp failed to rebuild` error is usually related to incompatible node version. I checked the [bigint-buffer NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bigint-buffer)  page and looks like it was last published 4 years

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this package instead, which provides prebuilt binaries: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@trufflesuite/bigint-buffer

With prebuilt binaries, you won't need to be running `node-gyp` to build the native dependency from source, and that should circumvent your problem.

---

**From the README:**

> This is a fork of the original bigint-buffer by @no2chem. This fork prebuilds the binaries using prebuildify. The binaries are built (and tested) for win32, linux, and darwin platforms, node versions 10-16, and x64 architecture. This should allow windows users to use the utility without installing windows-build-tools.

---

I can't guarantee it will work on Node 20, but it's [at least upgraded to support Node 18](https://github.com/trufflesuite/bigint-buffer/pull/4) - so you can give it a try at least.

---

**I see you mentioned:**

> Package bigint-buffer uses in package @solana/web3.js

What you can try is using Yarn's `resolutions`, or npm/pnpm's `overrides`

In Yarn I think you can achieve it like this in your `package.json`:

```js
  "resolutions": {
    "bigint-buffer": "@trufflesuite/bigint-buffer@^1.0.0"
  }
```

---

**If none of that works:**

I'm not certain which build tools versions are truly necessary but this seemed to be the minimum set with which I could reliably build any native dependencies I needed - but you may simply be out of luck with such an old and unmaintained dependency.

[image]
[image]